# Adding new window when presenting UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a trouble when trying to add a new window manually into screen when already presented UIImagePicker (images bellow). The purpose is, replace current status bar by new one. Then I can control which content is displayed on that.

[image]

After adding, UIImagePicker has been dismissed and presenting screen is displayed with no status bar and no new status bar.

[image]

And here is my code, just simple few lines of code

```
_newWindow              = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame];
UIView *_newView        = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewStatusView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
_newView.frame          = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
[_newWindow addSubview:_newView];

_newWindow.rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
_newWindow.windowLevel        = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1; 
_newWindow.hidden             = NO;
```

Update: here is what I expected:

[image]

I would like to create the red zone that displays on top of all view controllers, image pickers, alert controllers, presented view controllers, etc... and it lays on on all project screens. So i decided to use new window for that.

Comment: Why do you want to add a new window, not just a new view ?

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot bcos i want to display new status bar on whole app screens

Comment: You can simply enable / disable status bar on views ;)

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot it's impossible. That means you have to check on each view controller right? and i wanna display other contents onto new status bar

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to add a window on top of the status bar and hide it, and then display your own status bar in that window's hierarcy?

Comment: @LeoNatan i've updated my expectation. Please have a look on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to show/hide the status bar:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

No need to add a view beneath it.

**Update:**

You may subclass `UINavigationBar` to keep the size of it 64px like this:

```
#import "TANavigationBar.h"

@implementation TANavigationBar

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, 64);
    return newSize;
}

@end
```

Later on you can use this navigation bar when you initialize your navigation controller like this:

```
UINavigationController* nvc= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[nvc setValue:[[TANavigationBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
```

This way you will not lose the status bar margin.

Comment: i wanna custom contents on new status bar. that's why i need to add new status bar

Comment: Please have a look at the edit. You will be able to use the blank space.

Comment: unfortunately, i have a tab bar at bottom of screen, it means i have many navigation bars. So it's not really a solution. But thank you @atulkhatri. I still need an explanation, how it be like that.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer. You can reuse the same navigation bar for each of your `UINavigationController`

Comment: Thank you atulkhatri. Your solution works perfect, but that's not my expectation. Sorry, i didn't show you my expectation. My fail